# Are external DVD drives with separate data and power usb's faster?

Tags: dvd

Some external DVD drives have a single USB 3.0 for both power and data, while others have a USB 3.0 for data and a separate USB 2.0 for power. Does the second kind have faster data speeds - or are they the same?

Answer (score 1):

If both use USB 3.0 for data, then there is no reason, why should one be faster. However if those DVD drives declare different speed, you should believe its specs.

The separate USB 2.0 just for power, is probably only used, when the USB 3.0 port isn't capable of delivering sufficient power. The USB 3.0 specs define minimum ability of 4.5 W, which may not be sufficient for DVD drive. The battery charging specs assures up to 7.5 W and the USB power delivery specification declares up to 100W, however it must be suppored by the PC, wires and the powered device.